# How to get a database table data in a new module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

I want to create a new module in which I would like to have data of a specific database table. Is it possible ? If yes, please guide !

Answer (score 4):

Create your custom module as per your requirements, then in the model of your module create the following method.

> Vendor\Module\Model\YourModelName

```
public function getYourRequiredData()
{

      $select =$this->_getResource()->getConnection()->select()->from($this->_getResource()->getTable('blog_post'))->where(1);
      $data = $this->_getResource()->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: custom_id  ?  If I want to get recent blogs post from blog_post table? what I should do then ?

Comment: remove the where clause and replace your_custom_table_name with  blog_post table

Comment: custom_id is your primary key in your table it could be with any name , I include the custom_id if you want to get data specific to some particular Id . If you want to fetch all the records , then you don't need that custom_id

Answer (score 2):

( I believe you have created your module already but missing DB table part )
To create table for your module you need to have file Learner\Blog\Setup\InstallSchema.php:

```
<?php
  namespace Learner\Blog\Setup;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

 class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
 {
/**
 * Installs DB schema     
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('learner_blog_post'))
        ->addColumn(
            'post_id',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Post ID'
        )
        ->addColumn('url', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 100, ['nullable' => true, 'default' => null])
        ->addColumn('title', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Blog Title')
        ->addColumn('content', Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', [], 'Blog Content')
        ->addColumn('is_active', Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '1'], 'Is Active?')
        ->addColumn('creation_date', Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, ['nullable' => false], 'Creation Date')
        ->addColumn('update_date', Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, ['nullable' => false], 'Update Date')
        ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('blog_post', ['url_key']), ['url_key'])
        ->setComment('Magento 2 Blog');

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

}

here is nice tutorial which will guide you to develop module from scratch with configurations, save post(s) in table and view.

https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow the following steps:

create file app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

create file app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

create file app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ModuleName.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;

class ModuleName extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'cache_tag';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'cache_tag';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'cache_tag';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

create file app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName.php

```
  <?php

    namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

    class ModuleName extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
    {

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('table_name', 'table_primary_key');
    }

}
```

create file app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'table_primary_key';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'table_collection';
    protected $_eventObject = 'table_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ModuleName', 'Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName');
    }
}
```

Then step to get table data :

```
<?php 
//Get Object Manager Instance
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$tableData = $objectManager->create('Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ModuleName')->getCollection();
```